# galois norm and trace of field extensions

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $K \subset L \subset E$ and let Nm$_{E/K}(x)$ and  Tr$_{E/K}(x)$ be its norm and trace, the determinant and trace of $x$ acting by multiplication on $E$. How can one show that $$
Nm_{E/K}(x)=Nm_{L/K}(Nm_{E/L}(x)), Tr_{E/K}(x)=Tr_{L/K}(Tr_{E/L}(x))?
$$
It's easy for separable extensions, but I have no idea for arbitrary one.

Comment: Two things: I would say "field norm and trace", because here there is no Galois structure; also, perhaps you mean "$x$ acting by multiplication on $E$"?

Comment: Trace isn't bad. Take a look here for norm: http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/154Page/handouts/normtrace.pdf

Comment: This is done in detail e.g. in Lang's "Algebra", chapter 8, §5 .